# Creating a new column via file name

Tags: python, pandas

I will like to read multiple file and add a new column year. 
File Name: Shirt_2016, Shirt_2017, Shoe_2018, Shoe_2019,

```
rawfolder = 'c:/users/a/desktop/item'
A = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('%s/Shirt_2016' %(rawfolder), sheetname="sheet1", header=None)
B = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('%s/Shirt_2017' %(rawfolder), sheetname="sheet1", header=None)
C = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('%s/Shoe_2018' %(rawfolder), sheetname="sheet1", header=None)
D = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel('%s/Shoe_2019' %(rawfolder), sheetname="sheet1", header=None)
.
.(Script to run)
.
```

How do I create a year column extract with regards to '%s/Shoe_2019' and read the file at at time in the script. 
I have tried the following:

```
df['Year'] = (os.path.basename([A,B,C,D]).split('.')[0].split('_')[1])
```

Comment: for every file you would have to use separatelly `os.path.basename("%s/Shirt_2016")`

Comment: in every filename four last chars create year then `"%s/Shirt_2016"[-4]`. OR use that it is last element when you split("_") - so `"%s/Shirt_2016".split("_")[-1]`. But still you should do this for every filename separatelly. So I would create list with filenames and later use `for`-loop to read files and generate column `Year`

Answer (score 0):

I would create list with filenames

```
filenames = ['Shirt_2016', 'Shirt_2017', 'Shoe_2018', 'Shoe_2019', ...]
```

and then use `for`-loop to read files

```
rawfolder = 'c:/users/a/desktop/item'
all_df = []

for name in filenames:
   path = os.path.join(rawfolder, name)
   temp_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(path, sheetname="sheet1", header=None)
   all_df.append(temp_df)
```

and use this list to create column

```
df['Year'] = [name[-4:] for name in filenames]
```

Comment: Do i need to do df=pd.concat(all_df)?

Comment: `all_df` is normal list with many `df` - if you need one `df` then you have to concatenate them or create empty  `df` at start and inside `for`-loop append directly to this `df` - ie. `df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Are you able to show me the for loop if i start my df empty

Comment: use `df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)` instead of `all_df.append(temp_df)` and rest is the same.

Comment: Shirt_2016.xlsx does not seem to work for this: df['Year'] = [name[-4:] for name in filenames]

Comment: in question you use `'%s/Shirt_2016'` without `.xlsx` then problem is that you put wrong information in question.

Comment: if you have all filenames with `.xlsx` then what is the problem to use `name[-9:-5]` ? ie. `"Shirt_2016.xlsx"[-9:-5]` gives `2016`